# Throwing std bad_alloc even after resizing a 2D vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, bad-alloc

I have the following code:

```
struct elements
{
    char status;
    int value;
};
class matrix
{
    vector<vector <elements> > mat;
    int varNum;
    int ConNum;
public:
    void resetmatrix(int varnum, int connum)
    {
        varNum = varnum;
        ConNum = connum;
        mat.resize(connum, vector<elements>(varnum) );
    }
    matrix(int x, int y)
    {
        varNum = 0;
        ConNum = 0;
    }
};
matrix mat(0,0);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])      //main function
{
    int variables,cubes;
    variables=25;
    cubes= 10000000;
    cout<<"Variables= "<<variables<<endl<<"Cubes= "<<cubes<<endl;
    mat.resetmatrix(variables, cubes);
    cout<<"hello";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error

[image]

I thought this type of error only occurs when you haven't resized your vector. But I am resizing it. Can anyone tell me why this happens? is it because the value of cubes is very high (10 million)?

Comment: You are requesting 2GB, is that too much for your computer?  Are you compiling a 32 or 64 bit program?

Comment: My laptop has 16 GB, and I am compiling a 32 bit program. Should I try it on a different PC with better specs?

Comment: Asking for that much contiguous RAM even under 64-bit is asking for trouble.  Under 32-bit, that might barely work, but I wouldn't count on it. Any way to break those allocs up a bit - 10 200M alloc is easier to make than 1 2G one.

Comment: If you're running 32bit, the 16gB RAM is irrelevant. Each `element` is likely 8 bytes with padding and alignment. A `std::vector<element>` of size 25 will contain a pointer and size (*likely* 4 bytes each), then the dynamic 25*8 bytes for the actual elements. So each will be about 208 bytes. Now multiply that by ten-million and you arrive at 1.93 gB required total space (76.3 mB minimum contiguous).  If doing this on Windows, *forget it*. 32bit you only have 2GB total user-space including program and data, Between libs and your code and data and stack, you probably eat well past that.

Comment: That said, compile for 64bit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I will look into it.